# How to filter out multiple values in one custom dimension - Google Analytics Reporting API V3?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters, google-reporting-api

I need to save multiple values against one custom dimension, so I saved that using comma-separated values

For example, an article falls into multiple categories like blogs, news, cricket.

Also, the categories name can be changed, so I tried to save id instead of categories in google analytics custom dimension.

The following code sets the value in the custom dimension. I m using comma-separated values for multiple ids. Assume one article has 3 categories with the following ids 1, 3, 11 so I will save that id in the **custom dimension**

```
(<any>window).ga('set', 'dimension1', '1,3,11');(<any>window).ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Similarly more data will be inserted with their respective ids

In the UI, the user can filter out multiple categories, assume user has filter out 3 categories with 1, 9 and, 31 ids.

So accordingly to the selected filter, it should be returned those data only whose id 1 or 9 or 31 exists in dimension 1

```
let gaData: any = {
      'start-date': st_date,
      'end-date': end_date,
      'ids': "a:myviewid", // <-- Replace with the ids value for your view.
      'metrics': 'ga:pageviews,ga:timeOnPage,ga:sessions',
      'dimensions': "ga:dimension1,ga:dimension5",
      'start-index': 1 + (this.pageNo - 1) * this.pageSize,
      'max-results': this.pageSize,
      'filters': //some expression will be added
    }
```

The final URL will be like
https://content.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?start-date=2021-04-26&end-date=2021-05-26&ids=ga:myviewid&metrics=ga:pageviews,ga:timeOnPage,ga:uniquePageviews&dimensions=ga:dimension3,ga:dimension2&start-index=1&max-results=10&filters=someexpresson

If any other approach required to save the data, then please let me know as well

Any suggestion will be helpful.

**Thanks in advance**